# mysql error 1064 when inserting

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(country,ping,order) VALUES (China,1,1)' at line 1

this is my code

```
INSERT INTO  
  (country, ping, order) 
VALUES 
  ('China', '1', '1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the Table Name.  Try:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLENAME (country,ping,order) VALUES ('China','1','1');
```

Answer (score 2):

are ping and order text fields or numeric?  if numeric remove the ticks from the 1's

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (country,ping,order) VALUES ('China',1,1)
```

could also be reserved word try:

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (country,`ping`,`order`) VALUES ('China',1,1)
```

Comment: and yes order is a reserved word:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: +1 for answer, +1 for adding a link to the list of reserved words in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement is missing the table name:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_name,...) VALUES (expr,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing table name. also make sure that those quotes are necessary